# I want to create a dynamic pivot table which i can publish as view in sql server. please see more details below

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

There are 2 tables table one has acctrefno and date_purchased
Table no 2 has the date paid and payment amount
Here is sample data for table 1
acctrefno   FirstPayDate
5   2009-11-05
22  2012-04-15
28  2017-08-15
29  2018-09-15
Here is the sample data for table 2
acctrefno   FirstPayDate    date_paid   payment_amount
5   2009-11-05      2009-11-13      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2009-12-07      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-01-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-02-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-03-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-04-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-05-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-06-07      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-07-06      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-08-05      77.86
5   2009-11-05      2010-09-07      77.86
22  2012-04-15      2012-05-31      173.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-06-11      168.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-06-25      173.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-07-02      168.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-08-13      125.00
22  2012-04-15      2012-08-31      48.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-09-17      125.00
22  2012-04-15      2012-10-10      48.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-10-22      125.00
22  2012-04-15      2012-11-05      48.48
22  2012-04-15      2012-11-13      125.00
28  2017-08-15      2017-08-14      136.00
28  2017-08-15      2017-09-11      170.00
28  2017-08-15      2017-10-17      136.00
28  2017-08-15      2017-11-15      136.00
28  2017-08-15      2017-12-13      170.00
28  2017-08-15      2018-04-16      142.78
28  2017-08-15      2018-05-04      135.98
28  2017-08-15      2018-05-21      102.60
28  2017-08-15      2018-11-20      4.00
28  2017-08-15      2018-11-20      132.00
28  2017-08-15      2018-12-19      8.00
28  2017-08-15      2018-12-19      135.98
28  2017-08-15      2018-12-19      26.02
28  2017-08-15      2019-01-17      4.00
28  2017-08-15      2019-01-17      109.96
28  2017-08-15      2019-01-17      22.04
28  2017-08-15      2019-02-14      4.00
29  2018-09-15      2018-09-17      155.48

I am looking to get an output something like this
loan_number Month -4    Month -3    Month -2    Month -1    Month 0 Month 1 Month 2 Month 3 Month 4 Month 5 Month 6 Month 7 Month 8 Month 9 Month 10    Month 11    Month 12    Month 13
203026  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86   77.86
259796  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    173.48  341.96  168.48  173.48  125.00  173.48  173.48  173.48  216.96  168.48  125.00  221.96  125.00
428086  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    136.00  170.00  136.00  136.00  170.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    142.78  238.58  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
550343  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    155.48  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

here Month 0 means if the month of the date paid is equal to the month of first pay date, month 1 is one month after the first pay date, and month -1 is one month before the first pay date.

The reason why I want to create a dynamic query is there are more than 100 thousand accounts all started at different times within the last 6 years and have different payment dates. There is already a working solution for this query but the problem is it is not dynamic for the month's column. you have to specify month columns manually.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are 100's of examples of pivots and cross tabs on Stack Overflow; why didn't those work?

Comment: Not able to convert Months from the date purchase.

Comment: Probably because `'December 2018 '` Isn't a `date`, it's a `varchar`. Is `Payment Date` also a `varchar`? You need to fix your data first, if so.

Comment: What does the month 0 mean? Is it january? Is it a month that won't exist ever?

Comment: Here the meaning of Month 0 is (same month as date purchase) i.e. if date purchase is December 2018 (December 2018 = Month 0, January 2019 = Month, February 2019 = Month 3 and so on.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but consider date purchased as month purchased there is no significance of day the only month is significant.

Comment: What did your simple pivot function look like?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need dynamic SQL

The only trick was to convert the string into dates, and then it was a small matter to calculate the `datediff(MONTH,...)`

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=02daa1826ff89aafd57c0fac3e6c7a6b)**

```
Select ID
      ,[Month 1] = IsNull([1],0)
      ,[Month 2] = IsNull([2],0)
      ,[Month 3] = IsNull([3],0)
      ,[Month 4] = IsNull([4],0)
      ,[Month 5] = IsNull([5],0)
 From  (
            Select ID
                  ,Item = DateDiff(MONTH,try_convert(date,replace([Date Purchase],' ',' 1, ')),try_convert(date,replace([Payment Date],',',' ')))
                  ,Value =[Payment Amount]
            From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ID      Month 0  Month 1    Month 2  Month 3    Month 4  Month 5
1550    0.00     120.00     120.00   0.00       0.00     0.00
1551    0.00     130.00     135.00   0.00       90.00    0.00
1552    0.00     0.00       102.00   0.00       900.00   0.00
```

Comment: The table has around 28,000 rows and 36 such months. Can you please help me how to run this query on such large dataset.

Comment: @Shrey 28,000 rows is nothing.  I think the pattern presented it quite clear.  You will just have to extend out to 36 months... copy paste will help.

Comment: Thank you @John I am trying to use the same query for other data, there are 2 different tables for the open date (dare purchase) when I am trying to join the tables in is not working can you please help.

Comment: @Shrey I'm on a call.  I would suggest that you post another question with a small data sample and desired results.  If I can't, I'm sure someone else can

Comment: @Shrey The syntax looks good,  However, without the data structures and formats of [open date] and [date paid]  there is not much I can add.

Comment: @Shrey Are [open date] and [date paid] are DATES or STRINGS ?  What is the actual datatype?  Do they really look like the sample data in the original question?  I have a hard time believing a database is storing dates as strings.

Comment: It worked there was a small error. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Shrey Well Done!